# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoun

Tags: java, compilation

```
 java -cp /home/gjhawar/kafka/core/src/main/scala/examples TestProd.class
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: TestProd/class
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestProd.class
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    Could not find the main class: TestProd.class.  Program will exit.
```

Why am i getting this error even thought the Class file is there in this directory .. Do I have to include the path to the jar files too in   java command?

Answer (score 0):

Your call is invalid. Replace `TestProd.class` with `TestProd`.

Comment: I guess/hope that `/home/gjhawar/kafka/core/src/main/scala/examples` is actually the folder containing said class. If it is also the current directory then it may just as well have been `.`. Sorry about the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure about what the package you declare in TestProd, I guess you should run it by:

```
java -cp /home/gjhawar/kafka/core/src/main/scala examples.TestProd
```

and if TestProd is written in scala, you have to include scala-library.jar in your classpath

Answer (score 0):

If your code file is HelloWorld.java then

```
To compile : javac [-options] <path>/HelloWorld.java
To execute : java  [-options] <path>/Helloworld
```